# coalesce in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) (and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)) and [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

I have this code:

```js
var products = _.map(items, function(item) {
    return new ProductModel({
        title: item.product.title,
        description: item.product.description,
        link: item.product.link,
        'image-src': item.product.images[0].link,
        'image-height': item.product.images[0].height,
        'image-width': item.product.images[0].width
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, everything might be `null`. By everything I mean that `item, item.product, item.product.images, item.product.images[0]` and so on might be `null`s.

I am looking for something like "coalesce" that:

1. will know how to handle `null`s and will not throw exceptions for `item.product` if `item` is `null`.
2. will allow me to provide a default value if there was a `null`.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: It's better to provide default values in the model...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean `&&` and rely on [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
...
'image_src': item && item.product && item.product.images && item.product.images[0] && item.product.images[0].link,
'image_height': item && item.product && item.product.images && item.product.images[0] && item.product.images[0].height,
...
```

More likely, you don't want to perform the same test across so many lines. I would store your return value with its various attributes set to some sane default and then conditionally add the real values if your `item.product.images[0]` is non-null:

```
var returnObject = { /* default values here */ }, product, image;

if (product = item && item.product) {
    returnObject.title = product.title,
    returnObject.description = product.description,
    returnObject.link = product.link
};

if (image = product && product.images && product.images[0]) {
    returnObject['image-src'] = image.link;
    returnObject['image-height'] = image.height;
    returnObject['image-width'] = image.width;
}

return returnObject;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first `.filter` out the empty products:

```
var goodItems = _.filter(items, function(item) {
     return 'product' in item;
});
```

and the simplify the image tests by supplying an empty object if the one in the `product` doesn't exist:

```
var products = _.map(goodItems, function(item) {
    var product = item.product;
    var img = (product.images && product.images[0]) || {};
    return new ProductModel({
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        link: product.link,
        'image-src': img.link,
        'image-height': img.height,
        'image-width': img.width
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a default value for `null`s, then you could create a helper function like this:

```
var coalesce = function(obj, path, defaultValue) {
  while(obj != null && path.length) {
    obj = obj[path.shift()];
  }
  return (obj == null ? defaultValue : obj);
};
```

You would use it as follows:

```
coalesce(item, ["product", "title"], "Default title");
coalesce(item, ["product", "images", 0, "link"], "Default image link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is anything like that but I think you may create and use custom functions as below:

```
    return new ProductModel({
             title: getPorductAttribute(item,'title'),
             description: getPorductAttribute(item,'description'),
             link: getPorductAttribute(item, 'link'),
             'image-src': getImageAttirbute(item,0,'link'),
             'image-height': getImageAttirbute(item,0,'height'),
             'image-width': getImageAttirbute(item,0,'width')
            });


  function getPorductAttribute(item, attributeName){
       if(!(item && item.product)) 
           return defaultValue;
       return item.product.getAttribute(attributeName);
   }

  function getImageAttirbute(item, index, attributeName){
       if(!(item && item.product && item.product.images)) 
           return defaultValue;
       return item.product.images[index].getAttribute(attributeName);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical OR operator "||" to coalesce, as described here...

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/10/14/JavaScript-Gem-Null-Coalescing-using-the-OR-Operator

> var something = maybeNothing || 0;

Works against both null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure what the object actually is. You can do the good old try-catch...

```js
var testObject = {
  alpha: {
    beta: null
  },
  gama: {
    delta: null
  }  
};

try {
    console.log(testObject.alpha.beta.gama.delta);
} catch(err) {    
    alert(err.message);
}
```

This will not break your app, since the error is not `throw`ed. What you can do inside the catch statement is to fill your object with the default that is missing.